# Running 32bit LXC on 64 bit host machine?

Tags: docker, lxc

I was thinking that 64 bit host machine can launch 32 bit LXC as we have a option of specifying arch during LXC creation.

```
 hostmc$> lxc-create -n ubuntu -t ubuntu -- i386
```

Host machine:

```
 hostmc$> uname -a Linux D 3.11.0-26-generic #45~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 04:02:35 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

But then on login in to the 32 bit LXC container, I find uname -a specify the arch as x86_64 and even running file command also specify the arch as x86_64 instead of i386

```
   hostmc$> lxc-console -n ubuntu

   ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ uname -a
   Linux ubuntu 3.11.0-26-generic #45~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 04:02:35 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

   ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ file /bin/ls
   /bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x37cdd635587f519989044055623abff939002027, stripped
```

Answer (score 3):

On my Debian 8.2 (jessie), I get:

```
root@srv1:~# uname -a
Linux srv1 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u4 (2015-09-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux

root@srv1:~# lxc-create -n vm -t debian --dir /data/vm -- -a i386
...
root@srv1:~# lxc-start -n vm
...
(in the VM)
root@vm:~# uname -a
Linux vm 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u4 (2015-09-19) i686 GNU/Linux
```

The key difference with your example is the -a flag.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is late, but it might be helpful to someone.

I did it in Ubuntu Bionic with a Bionic 32-bit guest with the following:

```
sudo lxc launch images:ubuntu/18.04/i386 GuestName
# run with 
sudo lxc exec GuestName bash
```

and `uname -a` returns:

```
Linux MachineName 4.15.0-46-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 6 09:33:07 UTC 2019 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

So it's 32-bit, and the application I'm debugging confirmed it.

Answer (score 0):

When the host runs a 64 bit system the containers will always show a 64 bit system when you execute `uname`.

Containers and the host share the same Linux kernel instance. Containers are encapsulated processes but they still run in the host kernel. And if the host kernel is a 64 bit kernel the container processes are always processes that are executed 64 bit.

Comment: so I can't run 32 bit application created in container using arch i386 in 64 bit host machine?

Comment: Currently it is only possible to run on 64 bit. Please also have a look at [this github issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/136).